# UPDATE in mySQL Query not working?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I'm doing my website again and I want to edit or update the values of the rows so I went to phpmyadmin and check what is the code for updating values so I have this:

```
UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `title` = 'My Title', `message` = 'My Message' WHERE  `table`.`id` =2 LIMIT 1 ;
```

So I tried rephrasing it like this on PHP:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title = '$title', message = '$message' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
```

But when I tried checking my table, it doesn't change.

By the way, there are no errors showing.

Comment: What is the content of `$title` and `$contents`? Also you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @bsdnoobz No, using mysql_real_escape_string() is no longer best practice. The whole mysql_ family of functions are no longer recommended. You should use the mysqli_ functions or the PDO library instead. These along with parameterised queries will provide good SQL injection protection.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the constructed query? Have you checked the id you're looking for does exist? btw if id is a PK you don't need the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: Are you correctly connected to your database, does SELECT work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title = '" . $title . "' message = '" . $message . "' WHERE id =2 LIMIT 1");

What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @JuvarAbrera OK, perhaps it could be a character encoding problem.

[Convert HTML entities to character codes (e.g. &#39;)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)  |  

[Convert character codes to HTML elements:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will do

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title = '{$title}', message = '{$message}' WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title = '$title', message = '$message' WHERE id=$id");`

Or to prevent SQL injection

`mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE posts SET title = '%s', message = '%s' WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($title), mysql_real_escape_string($message), mysql_real_escape_string($id)));`

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

mysql_query('UPDATE posts SET title = "' . $title .'", message = "' . $message .'" WHERE id=' . $id . ' LIMIT 1');

Answer (score 1):

You have SQL injection. Which means that a single quote in your message will break the query. Any variable you pass to your query, no matter if it comes from user input, was retrieved from the database, or has hard-coded value, has to be properly escaped. In your case, since you are using mysql* family of function, `mysql_real_escape_string` is needed. But you can do you a favor by migrating to `mysqli` (which is really simple process) or `PDO`, and use `Prepared statements`. When you are using prepared statements, you can forget about escaping, and bind directly the variables to the placeholders in the query.

Answer (score 1):

probably you have quotations in your variables so you get a error.

you have two soloutions:

1. **use this syntax** : mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title = '".$title."', message = '".$message."' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
2. or better to use the standard php function 'mysql_real_scape_string()' for each variable going to a sql command so each disallow character will be prefixed by a backslash and then there's no problem form you.

Answer (score 0):

You are *not using the correct* **text box name** *for referring* in **jQuery or script**

Please correct it